# javax.websocket.DeploymentException: The HTTP response from the server [HTTP/1.1 200 OK ] did not permit the HTTP upgrade to WebSocket

Tags: spring, websocket

I have question, i'm make application REST API spring for fingerprint using websocket, i have already tried to connect websocket and that's work using button click from interface but after i tried to connect to websocket from localhost:8080/filename/1 url bar always showing, did not permit the HTTP upgrade to websocket can someone help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share the error message, including the "caused by"?

Comment: @zee thank's for answer my question, error message i'm place here https://pastebin.com/raw/44VM7M1k , caused i want to make application for fingerprint service using websocket